# javascript array.Join continious srings values into new array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i have this array = ["john", "mike", "george", 55, "hello", 344, "goodmorning"]
and i want to take this:["johnmikegeorge",55,"hello",344,"goodmorning"].I want where there are continuous strings to unite them into one.

```
  var s = ""
    var new_data = []
    var pin = ["john", "mike", "george", 55, "hello", 344, "goodmorning"]
    for (let i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
      if (typeof pin[i] === "string") {
        s = s + pin[i]
        new_data.push(s)
      } else {
        s = ""
        new_data.push(pin[i])
      }
    }
    console.log(new_data)
```

In previous code i take this ["john", "johnmike", "johnmikegeorge", 55, "hello", 344, "goodmorning"]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've modified what you already have to make it work. whenever you get a number, you push the concatenated string that you found before that number and then push the number. the if condition after the for loop is to check if you have more strings after the last number is pushed.

```
var s = "";
var new_data = []
var pin = ["john", "mike", "george", 55, "hello", 344, "goodmorning"]

for (let i = 0; i < pin.length; i++) {
  if (typeof pin[i] === "string") {
    s = s + pin[i]
  } else {
    if (s !== "") {
      new_data.push(s);
      s = "";
    }
    new_data.push(pin[i])
  }
}
if (s !== "") {
  new_data.push(s);
}

console.log(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value and last item of the result set, if they are strings and add the actual string as well.

Otherwise push the item. This is either a starting string of a series or a number.

```js
var array = ["john", "mike", "george", 55, "hello", 344, "goodmorning"],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (typeof v === 'string' && typeof r[r.length - 1] === 'string') {
            r[r.length - 1] += v;
        } else {
            r.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```